# Importing DAViCal calendar into macOS Calendar app

Tags: calendar, ical, caldav

I installed DAViCal (v.1.1.4) on my Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) server under a subdirectory mydomain.com/davical/ and want to import it into my Calendar App (v11.0 (2855.1.2)) on my macOS 12.1, but I am failing:

The instructions from [Client Config Page](https://davical.org/clients.php) don't work and from [iCal Config Page](https://davical.org/clients.php?client=iCal) is highly outdated... I managed to import the calendar into Thunderbird (Lightning) and even an Android phone (with Calendar Sync), so I confirmed, that the server works.

How do I add a caldav account? What are the configs to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the [davical wiki](https://wiki.davical.org/index.php?title=Setup_for_Apple_Users) where it states:

> If you install DAViCal in a subdirectory, or run it on a port other than 8443 (SSL) or 8008 and 8800 (unencrypted) then clients using the Apple devices will need to go into the advanced settings and configure the full URL, as detailed in the installation instructions for iCal and iPhone (the iPod instructions are the same as for the iPhone).

So when creating an account, I chose `advanced` instead of `manual` with the following config:

Account Type: `Advanced`
Username: `user` 
Password: `mypass` 
Server Address: `mydomain.com/davical/caldav.php` 
Server Path: `/davical/caldav.php/user` 
Port: `433`

Optionally, you may have to enable the account at `Menu>Calendar>Preferences>Accounts`, where you can also edit the description.